# Heuristic function when it will run? unity ml agent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ml-agent

This is my Heuristic funtion,

```
public override void Heuristic(in ActionBuffers actionsOut)
    {
        base.Heuristic(actionsOut);
        ActionSegment<float> continuousActionsOut = actionsOut.ContinuousActions;

        continuousActionsOut[0] = 1;
        if (Input.GetKey(jumpKey))
        {
             
        }
    }
```

the `continuousActionsOut[0] = 1;` where to put it, inside the if statement or out? I'm not understanding the logic

this is my onActionReceived funtion

```
public override void OnActionReceived(ActionBuffers vectorAction)
    {
        ActionSegment<float> continuousActionsOut = vectorAction.ContinuousActions;

        if (Mathf.FloorToInt(continuousActionsOut[0]) == 1)
            overTake();
    }
```